Show/detected duplicated inputID in shiny
I'm wondering if it is possible to detect duplicated inputID in a shiny app without going through the code? (I just spent to much time going through code manually in a fairly large app).
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput("a", "One", NULL),
  pickerInput("a", "two", NULL),
  pickerInput("b", "three", NULL),
  pickerInput("b", "Four", NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Add devmode() and you'll see this when you start the app:

More generally, use modules and you're much less likely to have this problem.

Which is what I told @MLEN a month ago.

Another option is to use the shinytest2 package:
library(shinytest2)

record_test("path to your shiny app")

After recording the tests and you exit, it will run the test script in your R console and raise a warning like this:
[ FAIL 0 | WARN 4 | SKIP 0 | PASS 2 ]
Warning message:
! Shiny inputs should have unique HTML id values.
ℹ The following HTML id values are not unique:
• a
• b 

